# ng-click="x(data)" in one controller and want to get that data in another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

By using ng-click="x(data)" in one controller and want to get that data in another controller and by that data which is in Json format, I need to again send a request to server by this data.

Comment: We need more info.. how are these controllers related? Can you post some code?

Comment: Actually the scenario is....i am having a group of buttons and they get their id's dynamically...and that id contains a json data..if i click that button it will redirect to other partial html and there i need to get this id and extract the values related to this id from a json object...and show it in the view...I am facing dfficulties in getting the json values related to that id.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to communicate between controller would be to use a provider (Service). I would try to refrain from broadcasting on a rootScope which are more difficult to test.
Make sure that the shared state data is in the service not the controller. then each controller can delegate to this service.
See example [here](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html).